# Code is displayed even with entries in the database

Tags: php, database, search

The following code continues to be displayed even if there are entries in my database and I don't understand why. Am I missing something? I'm not sure if this makes sense, but help would be great. :)

```
if($numrows==0)
{
echo"<h3>Results</h3>";
echo"<p>Sorry, your search: &quot;".$escaped."&quot; returned zero results</p>";
}
```

Comment: Presumably $numrows is zero before getting here. Perhaps you should show how $numrows gets its value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the code you're having a problem with is the same as quoted in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826439/help-with-search-coding-please)... then the problem is here:

```
$numresults=mysql_query($query);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows(numresults);
```

You're missing a $ before numresults on the second line.

Answer (score 2):

how do you get $numrows? It can be the mistake.

What I usually do is:

```
if($numrows > 0 ){

  // Code

}else{
  echo"<h3>Results</h3>";
  echo"<p>Sorry, your search: "".$escaped."" returned zero results</p>";
}
```

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I would just put my query where you have //Code right? Because when I do that it just displays the else statement. :/

Comment: can you paste your query and how you get the $numrows value?

Comment: No //code is what you want to do when you have some rows. You have to query the DB first, in order to get numrows.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo "'$numrows'";
```

**Directly** above the if statement.  If output is not **'0'**, then the problem is how you're assigning 0 to $numrows.

Comment: The if block actually would currently get executed if $numrows were null (because the == operator doesn't compare types), but it would not if she changed it to if($numrows === 0)